# Using more than one condition at the same time in if else statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a question involving if else statements using Java. I'm stuck on how to put two conditions within the parenthesis or if that is even possible?

So far this is my code:

```
public class rollerCoaster {



    int age = 11;
    int weight = 81;

    if ( age <= 10 && weight < 10 ) {
            System.out.println("This person needs to ride the black roller coaster.");
    }
    else if ( age <= 10 && weight >= 80 && <= 200  ) {

    }
    else {

    }

    //The new part is this:

    else if ( condition_two ) {

    }

};
```

Comment: The compiler has no idea what's supposed to be under 200; you need to tell it that your formula is about `weight`: `age <= 10 && weight >= 80 && weight <= 200`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight oh okay thank you very much that makes total sense. Also how would I  create an input field into that code? so that some could enter age and weight?

Answer (score 0):

For the relational operator '<=' you need to provide two operands.  So your `else if` in your if statement should read:

```
else if ( age <= 10 && weight >= 80 && weight <= 200 ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firts of all the firts chart in the class name for convention need to be in uppercase, and the structure of the code I think it would be something like this

```
public class RollerCoaster {

static int age = 11;
static int weight = 81;


public static void main(String args[]) {
    if(age <= 10) {
        if(weight < 10) {
            System.out.println("This person needs to ride the black roller coaster.");  
        }else if(weight >= 80 && weight <= 200) {
            System.out.println("This person needs to ride the red roller coaster.");
        }else {
            System.out.println("The roller coaster is not able for this person");
        }
    }else{
        if(weight < 10) {
            System.out.println("This person needs to ride the black roller coaster.");  
        }else if(weight >= 80 && weight <= 200) {
            System.out.println("This person needs to ride the red roller coaster.");
        }else {
            System.out.println("The roller coaster is not able for this person");
        }           
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class RollerCoaster {

    static int age, weight; 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//this help take input from user

        System.out.println("Enter Your Age Below:");
            age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Weight Below:");
            weight = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("You entered "+age+" as your age, and "+ weight+" as your weight!");

//****** First Codition
        if(age < 11){
            if(weight <10){
                //Do somthing
            }else if(weight > 79 && weight < 201){
                //Do another thing
            }else{
                //Do something else
            }  
        }else{
//***** Second Codition
//no need to check if age > 10 since it obviously will
            if(weight >10){
                    //Do somthing
                }else if(weight < 80 && weight < 201){
                    //Do another thing
                }else{
                //Do something else
                }  
            }   
    }
}
```